# MS Reporting Services - Slow Reports

Tags: reporting-services, reportmanager

I created an annonymous SSRS web wrapper that had been working without error for several months. Recently we've had our year end release and the production version has had problems with, to my knowledge, one report. The Dev and Test environment produce the report without error it's just production where it has been failing. We've began to trouble shoot the problem with the following results:

The execution time for the stored procedure can at times be in seconds and other times in excess of 20 minutes.

The above is also true for rendering the report using report manager.

Once you get to the SSRS wrapper it completely fails. Even so considering there is a fluctuation in the amount of time the stored procedure executes it seems to me that even if I set the wrapper to not have a timeout the stored procedure may still be the culprit.

As for the report server, I'm not the DBA so I'm not familiar with the rs.config files. Also, I read something about the settings being set a certain way using IIS 6. According to the DBA it does not run off of IIS 6. Again, this is something I'm not familiar with.

Another thing I have a question about is parameter sniffing. There are three parameters being sent in, one for the City set as Text in RB 3.0 and Varchar in SQL, the month and year both set as int in RB 3.0 as well as integer in sql.

I know for a fact that the first time this error came about the server was reset and the report was produced without error. Since then they have been able to stabilize the server but now the report does not render. Anyone with trouble shooting advice please come to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a negative one. Sorry about the bad question. Anyway, the problem was the stored procedure. The DBA told me he had to reset the statistics.